# How do I scale the icon size of SVGs in wheelnav.js?

Tags: wheelnav.js

Is it possible to scale the size of the icons used within each wheel segment based on a breakpoint (ie. 1024 and over)?

e.g.:

```
if(window.innerWidth >= 1024){
 // wheel.sliceTransformCustom = makeIconsBigger!
}
```

I've got this working spectacularly well for my requirements, and this is the last hurdle :)

[image]

Updated with solution based on answer (decided to make icons smaller as lower resolutions to keep fidelity):

```
if(window.innerWidth < 1024){     
      wheel.sliceTransformFunction = sliceTransform().CustomTitleTransform;      
      wheel.sliceTransformCustom = new sliceTransformCustomization();    
      wheel.sliceTransformCustom.scaleString = "s0.65";

      wheel.sliceSelectedTransformFunction = sliceTransform().CustomTitleTransform;
      wheel.sliceSelectedTransformCustom = new sliceTransformCustomization();    
      wheel.sliceSelectedTransformCustom.scaleString = "s0.65";
}
```

Comment: I've currently gotten around this by creating separate sets of icons, and just defining which ones to use based on screen size. Would prefer and would be more efficient to be able to scale them, so leaving this question open in the event someone has a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ScaleTitleTransform for this.

```
if(window.innerWidth >= 1024){
   wheel.sliceTransformFunction = sliceTransform().ScaleTitleTransform;
}
```

There is an example [here](https://github.com/softwaretailoring/wheelnav/blob/v1.7.1/index.html#L73)

The ScaleTitleTransform default scale is 1.3.
You can find the default function [here](https://github.com/softwaretailoring/wheelnav/blob/v1.7.1/js/source/wheelnav.sliceTransform.js#L102)

Comment: Ahh great, thank you.

Took me a little while to figure out exactly how to implement what you mentioned for a custom value, but I got there ...not sure how to leave formatted code in this comment. Will see where else I can add.

Comment: Congratulations! :) Based on your screenshot, this site would be welcome here: https://wheelnavjs.softwaretailoring.net/spinit.html#worldwidewheel